# Multiple consumers polls same value twice from ConcurrentLinkedQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

I was widely using `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` for multiconsuming task queuing and never had this issue before. The scenerio is as follows:

1. Fill my queue with some tasks
2. Run multiple threads (in this particular case 2) that will be pooling tasks from queue
3. While queue is not empty, pool from queue and do your job.

The thing is, that **my consumers are pooling firs element TWICE**. To avoid confussion, I have already checked the queue for duplicate elements elements but there are none. What is going on? I don't know why, but syncing `queue.poll()` did not fixed this issue. How to resolve this?

My queue poll synchronizing wrapper (I didn't need it ever before, and this still not helping)
EDIT: As I have pointed out, it didn't help, but I had to try. Proposse correct approach.

```
public class MultipleConsumerBlockingQueue<T> extends ConcurrentLinkedQueue<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7994932568441881715L;
    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipleConsumerBlockingQueue.class);

    @Override
    public synchronized T poll() {
        T item = super.poll();
        return item;
    }

}
```

part of consuming threads

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                AdvancedSearchAgent agent = new AdvancedSearchAgent();
                while ((dp = queue.poll()) != null) {
                    log.info("**** for publication dates: {} - {}", sdf.format(dp.getFromDate()), sdf.format(dp.getToDate()));
                    agent.searchByPublicationDate(dp.getFromDate(), dp.getToDate());
                    log.info("Expected results count {} on {} pages", agent.getResultsCount(), agent.getPagesCount());
                    iterateOverResult(agent, handler);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                log.error("Unhanded error occured ****. Exiting method *****", ex);
            }

        }
```

generated output:

```
08:05:15.171 [main] INFO  ****  - Generated 10 date intervals for querying
08:05:15.174 [main] INFO  ****  - Created inner task 1
08:05:15.174 [main] INFO  ****  - Created inner task 2
Czas wykonania= 0 sekund  0 godzin 0 minut 0 sekund
08:05:15.178 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  **** - **** for publication dates: 01-02-2013 - 03-03-2013
08:05:15.178 [pool-2-thread-2] INFO  **** - ****  for publication dates: 01-02-2013 - 03-03-2013
```

EDIT:

Here is dump of of items in queue. No duplicates.

```
   1# -> Wt 2013-01-01 : Cz 2013-01-31
   2# -> Pt 2013-02-01 : N 2013-03-03
   3# -> Pn 2013-03-04 : Śr 2013-04-03
   4# -> Cz 2013-04-04 : So 2013-05-04
   5# -> N 2013-05-05 : Wt 2013-06-04
   6# -> Śr 2013-06-05 : Pt 2013-07-05
   7# -> So 2013-07-06 : Pn 2013-08-05
   8# -> Wt 2013-08-06 : Cz 2013-09-05
   9# -> Pt 2013-09-06 : N 2013-10-06
  10# -> Pn 2013-10-07 : Pt 2013-10-11
```

Comment: "I didn't need it ever before." You don't need it now.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that you are enqueuing the same object twice. You don't need wrappers or synchronization, `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is already thread safe.

Comment: @Flavio sorry, but I have checked that (and mentioned it in my question when I posted it). No duplicates.

Comment: Then you have two different queues, or did not dump the list content correctly. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` does not return the same object twice, the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Why nobody else didn't say just as you did that `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is safe to poll by multiple consumers? You are right it is, I have started to looking bug elsewhere and I have found it. Thanks and +1 ofc.

Comment: and what was the bug?

Comment: Check my own answer below. It was connected to shared `SimpleDateFormat` by worker threads and wrong log generation, not polling from queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty much impossible that `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is broken. It was tested in literary millions of applications for many years, and you are guaranteed that you won't poll the same element twice.

I can't see where you are defining `dp`. If this isn't a local variable, I sense a potential candidate... Try making it into a local variable and see if it still occurs.

Also this may sound silly but make sure you are polling from a single, identical `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` object (It's usually something silly like this).

Answer (score 3):

I had common bug - it involves NonThreadSafety of Dateformat. Polling from queue was just fine, only logs were generated with errors.
`sdf` is SimpleDateFormat object shared by worker (at the beginning it supposed to be only single thread so nobody cared). As it is not thread safe, wrong dates were formated. So sad I didn't catch that before. 
Thanks for all the comments and pointouts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `synchronized` method will never work as you expect because `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` doesn't use Java Monitor Pattern for Thread Safety. It uses a different approach as explained [here](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf).

Comment: What to use than? Implement own synchronized poll queue? No ready2go solutions in JDK?

Comment: @Antoniosss There is no actual evidence that concurrency is the problem, so no reason to think that synchronization is the solution.

Comment: Than what is? The code is preatty straightforward as to simple responsibility principle.